# unable to put css in gravity form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am trying to put css in gravity forms, actually, I want to remove the extra margin from the form to look it better in mobile view.

```
.gform_wrapper {
margin-left: -55px!important;
margin-bottom: 50px;
```

}

I am trying to remove the margin-left from -55 to 0 but it doesn't get any effect in the final results.
can anyone help me?

Website link: https://www.wegreen.ch/abonnemente/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries to remove the left margin. Add the following code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .gform_wrapper {
     margin-left: 0px!important;
  }
}
```